# Check out with Pay-Pal reset the connection

Tags: paypal, tcp

I have a web app that use paypal for checkout. It was working well few days ago. Now, I try to do a checkout and Paypal reset the connection. I'm using a sandbox account, sending the request to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/. I have a valid certificate from Paypal. My XML request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsi:SetExpressCheckoutReq xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SetExpressCheckoutRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
        <ErrorLanguage xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">en_US</ErrorLanguage>
        <Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">98.0</Version>
        <SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
            <OrderTotal currencyID="USD" />
            <ReturnURL>https://[my url site]?ppec=return</ReturnURL>
            <CancelURL>https://[my url site]/checkout.aspx?ppec=cancel</CancelURL>
            <Custom>100232</Custom>
            <cpp-header-image>https://[my url site]/themes/default/images/layout/invoice_logo.gif</cpp-header-image>
            <PaymentAction>Sale</PaymentAction>
            <BuyerEmail>some@email.com</BuyerEmail>
            <ChannelType>Merchant</ChannelType>
            <PaymentDetails>
                <OrderTotal currencyID="USD">280.51</OrderTotal>
                <ItemTotal currencyID="USD">270.00</ItemTotal>
                <ShippingTotal currencyID="USD">10.51</ShippingTotal>
                <HandlingTotal currencyID="USD">0.00</HandlingTotal>
                <TaxTotal currencyID="USD">0.00</TaxTotal>
                <InvoiceID>100232</InvoiceID>
                <ShipToAddress>
                    <Name>NAME SURNAME</Name>
                    <Street1>717 Some st</Street1>
                    <Street2 />
                    <CityName>City</CityName>
                    <StateOrProvince>ST</StateOrProvince>
                    <Country>US</Country>
                    <Phone>+15551234567</Phone>
                    <PostalCode>00000</PostalCode>
                </ShipToAddress>
                <PaymentDetailsItem>
                    <Name>Triángulo Isósceles</Name>
                    <Number>4444</Number>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    <Amount currencyID="USD">300.00</Amount>
                </PaymentDetailsItem>
                <PaymentDetailsItem>
                    <Name>Discounts</Name>
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                    <Amount currencyID="USD">-30.00</Amount>
                </PaymentDetailsItem>
            </PaymentDetails>
        </SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails>
    </SetExpressCheckoutRequest>
</xsi:SetExpressCheckoutReq>
```

A month ago I change the security protocol type from Tls to Tls1.2. My tests when I made the change were ok but know is not working. I traced the connection with Wireshark and I got from sandbox Paypal (173.0.82.78)

```
443 → 60191 [RST, ACK] Seq=4163 Ack=2365 Win=0 Len=0
```

Any idea?

Thanks. Sorry my English. If you don't understand something because that, don't hesitate to ask me anything.

Answer (score 1):

There are many apis that provided by paypal depend on your location .
please first check that the rest api is supported by your country or not . 
go to http://developer.paypal.com it's the biggest documentation and guide to use paypal apis i think express payment is the best for you it'll connect to the paypal site and the checkout will be done in really secure place . the documents and the api properties are documented in paypal website with really help ful examples .
You have to send your request using query string to this url https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/ .
the properties that you have to send can find on paypal website express checkout api rest .
Good Luck

Comment: The api is supported in my country and in USA where I'm doing the test through a proxy. I read again the api documentation and the xml is well formed. I'm sending the correct user, password and certificate, but for any reason paypal close the connection. The same code worked well last June.

Comment: the easier way is to pass all of your properties to paypal sandbox using query string and giving response from paypal, you have to send api signature and api id, and secret with other properties too for each request .